# Perl regex syntax generation

Tags: regex, perl, spss

This is a follow up to the question posted here: [Perl Regex syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358361/perl-regex-syntax)

The results from that discussion yielded this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <DATA>;

my $current_label = '';
my @ordered_labels;
my %data;
for my $line (@lines) {
    if ( $line =~ /^\/(.*)$/ ) { # starts with slash
        $current_label = $1;
        push @ordered_labels, $current_label;
        next;
    }
    if ( length $current_label ) {
        if ( $line =~ /^(\d) "(.*)"$/ ) {
            $data{$current_label}{$1} = $2;
            next;
        }
    }
}

for my $label ( @ordered_labels ) {
    print "$label <- as.factor($label\n";
    print "    , levels= c(";
    print join(',',map { $_ } sort keys %{$data{$label}} );
    print ")\n";
    print "    , labels= c(";
    print join(',',
        map { '"' . $data{$label}{$_} . '"'  }
        sort keys %{$data{$label}} );
    print ")\n";
    print "    )\n";
}

__DATA__
...A bunch of nonsense I do not care about...
...
 Value Labels
/gender
1 "M"
2 "F"
/purpose
 1 "business"
 2 "vacation"
 3 "tiddlywinks"

execute .
```

Essentially, I need to build the Perl to accommodate a syntax shorthand found in the SPSS file. For adjacent columns, SPSS allows one to type something like:

```
VALUE LABELS
/agree1 to agree5
1 "Strongly disagree"
2 "Disagree"
3 "Neutral"
4 "Agree"
5 "Strongly agree"
```

As the script currently exists, it will generate this:

```
agree1 to agree5 <- factor(agree1 to agree5
    , levels= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    , labels= c("Strongly disagree","Disagree","Neutral","Agree","Strongly agree","N/A")
    )
```

and I need it to produce something like this:

```
agree1 <- factor(agree1 
    , levels= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    , labels= c("Strongly disagree","Disagree","Neutral","Agree","Strongly agree","N/A")
    )
agree2 <- factor(agree2 
    , levels= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    , labels= c("Strongly disagree","Disagree","Neutral","Agree","Strongly agree","N/A")
    )
…
```

Comment: So you want help in converting the existing script to generate different output?  The difference seems minor: surely you should just be able to edit the `agree1` strings? Can you clarify which part you are having difficulty with?

Comment: Essentially, I need to make another for-loop when the SPSS syntax contains the shorthand `\var1 to varN`. As it currently exists, the script treat `var1 to varN` as a single variable, when it needs to create new variables for `var1, var2, var3, varN`

Comment: Chase: you will get much better help if you don't just explain what you want but also where you are having trouble doing it yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

main();

sub main {
    my @lines = <DATA>;
    my $vlabels = get_value_labels(@lines);
    write_output_delim($vlabels);
}

# Extract the value label information from SPSS syntax.
sub get_value_labels {
    my (@vlabels, $i, $j);
    for my $line (@_){
        if ( $line =~ /^\/(.+)/ ){
            my @vars = parse_var_range($1);
            $i = @vlabels;
            $j = $i + @vars - 1;
            push @vlabels, { var => $_, codes => [] } for @vars;
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ /^\s* (\d) \s+ "(.*)"$/x ){
            push @{$vlabels[$_]{codes}}, [$1, $2] for $i .. $j;
        }
    }
    return \@vlabels;
}

# A helper function to handle variable ranges: "agree1 to agree3".
sub parse_var_range {
    my $vr = shift;
    my @vars = split /\s+ to \s+/x, $vr;
    return $vr unless @vars > 1;

    my ($stem) = $vars[0] =~ /(.+?)\d+$/;
    my @n = map { /(\d+)$/ } @vars;
    return map { "$stem" . $_ } $n[0] .. $n[1];
}

sub write_output_delim {
    my $vlabels = shift;
    for my $vlab (@$vlabels){
        print $vlab->{var}, "\n";
        print join("\t", '', @$_), "\n" for @{$vlab->{codes}}
    }
}

sub write_output_factors {
    # You get the idea...
}

__DATA__
/gender
1 "M"
2 "F"
/purpose
 1 "business"
 2 "vacation"
 3 "tiddlywinks"
/agree1 to agree3
1 "Disagree"
2 "Neutral"
3 "Agree"
```

Comment: @FM - thanks for your response. My lack of knowledge of Perl is clearly limiting me here, and I can see that all the necessary information is here to accomplish what I'm after. I need to spend some time digesting how you have approached this problem. I like how you have broken each of the main tasks out into its' own sub routine.